# Problema al hacer un intent de fragmento a fragmento - android

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Buen día, tengo un problema con viajar de un fragmento a otro parece una pregunta bastante genérica y a pesar de toda la información que hay sobre el tema yo obtengo un resultado distinto normalmente debería de viajar hacia un segundo fragment pero en mi caso lo dibuja abajo de donde estoy:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se han dado cuenta cuando doy en el boton "Hacer un pedido" deveria de viajar al fragmento de categorias pero en lugar de eso solo lo dibuja abajo de mi fragmento principal, he probado infinidad de codigos pero todos me dan en mismo resultado, cual es la forma correcta de hacer un intent de fragmento a fragmento o que es lo que estoy haciendo mal? este es mi codigo:

```
FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fr.replace(R.id.home, new Categorias());
            fr.commit();
```

Tambien he probado codigo como este:

```
Categorias fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
FragmentGreen llf = new FragmentGreen();
ft.replace(R.id.home, llf);
ft.commit();
```

O como este:

```
Categorias categorias= new Categorias();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.home, cateogrias)
                .addToBackStack(Home.class.getSimpleName())
                .commit();
```

Pero como les mencione el resultado siempre es el mismo, espero me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Parece que no estás usando el [Componente de Navegación](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started?hl=es). Si no lo estás usando, te lo recomiendo. Android está apostando fuerte por una serie de componentes que facilitan bastante el código (cuando puedas lee sobre Android Jetpack). En este caso, la Navegación entre Fragmentos, opciones de menú, etc quedan integradas en un nuevo estilo de programación donde todo es mucho más fácil y con menos código. Por ejemplo, puedes usar tu Componente de Navegación para todo, creando incluso una App con una sola Activity.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano gracias por la sugerencia, revisando un poco la documentación me doy cuenta que al utilizar el Componente de Navegación debo cambiar toda la arquitectura del proyecto, en ese caso no tendría otro camino para poder adaptarlo a mi proyecto?

Comment: La mejor manera es esta, y no es tan complejo, solamente tienes que definir tu NavHost y un layout para cada fragmento o grupo de fragmentos y cambiar un poco de código (puedes aprovechar y pasar también a DataBinding). Cierto que hay que dedicarle un poco de tiempo (un par de días) a entender cómo funciona y luego irás sobre ruedas. Yo empecé a migrar mi App hace poco y es bastante fácil. Creo que optar por un modo obsoleto de resolver el problema, aunque parezca más fácil, no lo es. Las nuevas herramientas de Android evitan situaciones graves, como fugas de memoria y otras.